# How to split csv rows containing multiple string values based on comma but without considering comma inside curly brackets { }

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I am reading one csv file and trying to split its rows based on comma, Here in my case rows containing some values having comma as a part of that value and that value start and ends with { }.

My Split function:

```
    def process(self, row):
        """
        Splits each row on commas
        """
        Uid, controlNo, profileType, LAStpointDetail, LastPointDate = 
                                                         row.split(",")
```

My row example:

```
0923,41003,Permanent,{""Details"": [{""data"": {""status"": ""FAILURE"", ""id"": ""12345""}, ""DetailType"": ""Existing""}]},2019-06-27
```

In rows If you see "LAStpointDetail", it already contains multiple commas in it. How do I split this whole row based on comma.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to have here is [csv](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html) data, in which one column is encoded as [json](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html).

It's not possible to tell exactly how the data is quoted from the the question (it would have been better to paste the [repr](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#repr) of the row), but let's assume it's something like this:

```
'"0923","41003","Permanent","{""Details"": [{""data"": {""status"": ""FAILURE"", ""id"": ""12345""}, ""DetailType"": ""Existing""}]}","2019-06-27"'
```

If that's true, and you have a file of this data containing multiple rows, you can use the csv module to read it:

```
import csv
import json
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Remove the next line if the first row is not the headers.
    # next(reader)    # Skip header row.
    for row in reader:
        Uid, controlNo, profileType, LAStpointDetail, LastPointDate = row
        # Load embedded json into a dictionary.
        detail_dict = json.loads(LAStpointDetail)
        # Do something with these values.
```

If you only have a single row as a string, you can still use the csv module:

```
>>> row = '"0923","41003","Permanent","{""Details"": [{""data"": {""status"": ""FAILURE"", ""id"": ""12345""}, ""DetailType"": ""Existing""}]}","2019-06-27"'
>>> # Make the data an element in a list ([]).
>>> reader = csv.reader([row])
>>> Uid, controlNo, profileType, LAStpointDetail, LastPointDate = next(reader)
>>> print Uid
0923
>>> d = json.loads(LAStpointDetail)
>>> d
{u'Details': [{u'DetailType': u'Existing', u'data': {u'status': u'FAILURE', u'id': u'12345'}}]}
>>> print d['Details'][0]['data']['status']
FAILURE
```